# Module not found and the code given has no solution

Tags: github, npm, module

asalam,.good morning dev..
im looking for solution how to fix my hashlip art engine.below is the code mention,

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\asus 21.6.21\OneDrive\Desktop\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v1\index.js:2:39)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

Comment: im just stuck here for awhile trying to fix it with youtube and such on..still untill today

Comment: What is causing the error?